# c# execute shell command and get result

Tags: c#, shell, command, output, prompt

I am executing a command prompt command as follows:

```
string cmd = "/c dir" ; 
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process(); 
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd; 
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
proc.Start();
```

How to I get the output of the command?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try this

```
string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```